# URL cache and multi-tenancy

Tags: http, url, url-rewriting, multi-tenant

We've a HTTP server written in JAVA that is serving both dynamic and static resources. Some of these resources are cached using "Cache-Control" header. Everything is fine and work as expected.

That server is now supporting multi-tenancy meaning it can serve different contents (e.g., CSS) based on the actual tenant of the user being logged in the system.

The issue is that for the end-user (and the browser) the URL of a resource is the same whether it belongs to TenantA or TenantB and therefore is cached in the browser but this is not the same content as it depends on the tenant. As you can imagine this causes a lot of trouble once you change tenant on the same browser

```
/path/file1

tenant1 -> file1 contains 'hello'
tenant2 -> file1 contains 'see you'
```

Any brillant idea how to solve this issue ?